# "Decir para hacer algo" vs "Decir que haga algo"

Tags: coloquialismos, euskera

Vivo en el País Vasco, y escucho a menudo frases del estilo "Me ha dicho PARA ir a la playa" en vez de "Me ha dicho que vayamos a la playa"

¿Se utiliza únicamente aquí, como traducción literal del euskera "Esan dit hondartzara joaTEKO", o se utiliza en más sitios?

Comment: En Argentina, no se usa "para", pero se usa mucho "de": Me ha dicho DE ir a la playa.

Comment: Se uno no habla euskera, es imposible saberlo.

Comment: Yo solo he oído esa construcción en el País Vasco y Navarra, lugares donde se habla euskera. Pero no puedo asegurar que no se use en algún sitio más.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La expresión "Me ha dicho para ir a la playa", es habitual en otras partes de España, al menos en parte de Andalucía Oriental es común, de hecho es una locución oral tan natural, que apenas nos percatamos cuando la utilizamos.

- Me ha dicho para ir de compras.
- Me ha dicho para tomar tapas.
- Me dijo para ir de pesca.
- Te llamo para tocar.
- Me ha dicho para ir a la playa.

Realmente el sentido de estas frases expresan primero el deseo de "quedar" que suele aparecer como verbo omitido en este tipo de giros y después realizar la actividad que se señala en la oración.

- Me ha dicho para (quedar e) ir de compras.
- Me ha dicho (de quedar) para tomar tapas.
- Me dijo para (quedar e) ir de pesca.
- Te llamo para (quedar y) tocar.
- Me ha dicho (de quedar) para ir a la playa.

**P.D.** Hasta donde yo se, aunque "teko" puede significar "para", también significa "de", así en "Esan dit hondartzara joateko", más bien se interpreta como; "Me dijo que fuera a la playa" o "Me ha dicho de ir a la playa"  donde "para" más bien es un modo añadido de interpretación, pero no el más adecuado. La expresión en general, en este caso, pertenece al español común y no al euskera.